# AngularJS Directive for label with a textfield

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm new to angular directives, and I've been working on this project, where we use a forms on most of our pages.

Therefore, I figured it would be smart to make a custom directive, to create a label, with a following textfield.

However, What I've achieved so far, isn't really working, and I'm not sure why.

In particular, I can get my directive to work in  basic format, but when I try to implement ng-model, I get an angular error in my console.

My Script:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
    app.directive("labelWithTextfield", function() {
        return {
            require: '^ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                label: '@', inputName: '@'
            },
            template : "<label for='{{label}}' class='labelClass'>{{label}}     </label><br>"+
            "<input type='text' name='{{inputName}}' class='textFieldClass' required ng-model='internship.{{inputName}}' />",
        };
    });
</script>
```

My HTML tags:

```
<div label-with-textfield label="Navn" inputName="name" ></div>
<br>
<div label-with-textfield label="Adresse" inputName="address" ng-model="internships.name"></div>
```

My first rendering of the directive goes "fine", until it reaches the ng-model part, then i get this error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20not%20a%20valid%20identifier&p2=12&p3=internship.%7B%7BinputName%7D%7D&p4=%7B%7BinputName%7D%7D

Now as I said, I'm no expert, but I've been looking all over online, to try to find an example, but haven't been able to so far - Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try changing `ng-model='internship.{{inputName}}'` in your template to `ng-model='internship[inputName]'`

Comment: Oh wow, that actually seems to have worked! Thanks alot, I didn't see this in any of the related articles I've come across so far - Now I have something to work with! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your html tags should be kebab-cased:

```
<div label-with-textfield label="Navn" input-name="name" ></div>
```

That should fix your issue.

Comment: No, not for the variable naming - The camel case is just for the naming of the directive - Did test your suggestion never the less, but didn't change anything - Thanks for the suggestion tho :)